# gedit , regex to find all numbers between brackets

Tags: regex, gedit

I have a text file with these data :

(100%)
(100%)
(100%)
(100%)
(100%)
(100%)

I would like a regular expression to use in the find and replace of get edit to remove all the numbers between brackets and the percentage sign also

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
\([^\)]+\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/88ClwxG5sQM5rgyV)

---

This is specific to there being some numbers and a % symbol

```
\(\d+%\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/K_uU6p5o247uhTNK)

Answer (score 0):

In the search for text box you can write:

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

and in the replace with box you can write:

```
(number)
```

where number can be any number you want. e.g `(25)`